# Move window over Status bar

Tags: cocoa, window, statusbar

I have a borderless Window that can be dragged and resized around the screen.
It is used to retrieve coordinates and size to take a screenshot with `screencapture` command.

SelectionPanelController.m

```
#import "SelectionPanelController.h"

@implementation SelectionPanelController

@synthesize selectionPanelBackgroundView = _selectionPanelBackgroundView;

#pragma mark -

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    NSPanel *panel = (id)[self window];
    [panel setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
    [panel setLevel:NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel];
    [panel setOpaque:NO];
    [panel setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
    [panel setBackgroundColor:[NSColor clearColor]];
    panel.level = NSMainMenuWindowLevel + 1;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"SelectionPanel"];
    if(self)
    {
        //initialize stuff
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

The problem i am facing is that the window cannot be moved over the status bar.

If i set the window origin programmatically, it can be over the status bar, but moving manually it is not possible.

**How i can make it to be moveable over the status bar?**

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a similar problem, check the last post for a suggestion:
http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/136044-windows-above-the-menu-bar.html

PS: I was going to comment, but don't have enough rep, sorry.